# FBRequest Delegate method request:didLoad: is not getting called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, ipad

I'm using Facebook ios sdk for sharing in that i need to fetch user basic information like userName i'm doing something like below,
in @interface

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<FBRequestDelegate,FBDialogDelegate,FBSessionDelegate>
--------
@property (nonatomic,retain) FBRequest *fbRequestObj;
```

and in @implementation

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    fbRequestObj = [[FBRequest alloc] init];
    [fbRequestObj setDelegate:(id)self];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    NSString* name = [result objectForKey:@"name"];
    userName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Logged in as %@",name];       
}
```

but my problem here is the above FBRequest delegate is not at all getting called in any instance. Is my way of implementation is correct or not? if not plz guide me.
Any help is thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The way you alloc/init the `FBRequest` object doesn't look correct.
According to the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/request/), you can try to do the following instead :

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    /* create the params dictionary */
    self.fbRequestObj = [FBRequest requestWithParams:yourParamsDictionary
                                            delegate:self];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: i dont want to pass any params dict i just want the userName as soon as a user logged in in to FB, how can i fetch that data?

Comment: your question was about the delegate method not being called, I pointed out that your `FBRequest` object were not well alloc/init. Looking at the doc (again) let me think there must be some params to the request.. as FB can't guess what information you are trying to get.

Comment: according to my research i came to know something like this in fbDidLogin() method after finish just invoke [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self]; and then in  - (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result u can get details but still this dosent worked out!!!

Comment: good, but you just told the same as me. In your comment example, the request is still not alloc/inited like in the question, as I pointed out in my answer

Comment: thanks for reply,,,ya now i alloc inited as you said to me i dont have any parms for now so what can i pass there?

Comment: if you can retrieve the info without params, then try passing empty dictionary.